# How to distribute items of varying sizes into bins of varying sizes, such that percent utilization across all bins is minimized?

Tags: algorithms, partitions

I have a bunch of databases, each having different access patterns, such that each puts a different amount of load on its database cluster. I would like to distribute them around my set of database clusters such that the workload for the clusters is evenly distributed.

I looked at the [*k*-partition problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-partition_problem), which sounds close to what I want, except each of my database clusters has a different load capacity. That means I need an algorithm that minimizes what percent of load capacity is used on all clusters, whereas the *k*-partition problem minimizes the integer load on each cluster.

Does such an algorithm exist? And can anyone point me to a sample implementation of it?

Comment: In the special case that all center capacities are the same your problem is equivalent to k-partition, which is NP-hard (even when weights are polynomially bounded integers). In practice, you might solve the natural LP relaxation, then randomly round the solution. (E.g., Let variable $X_{ij}$ represent the fraction of database $i$ that the LP solution maps to cluster $j$. Choose a single random cluster $\hat j(i)$ to actually use for $i$ by drawing randomly from the distribution $p$ defined by $p_i = X_{ij}$.  Maybe polish this solution with some local improvement.

Comment: Can you please clarify what a "natural LP relaxation" is?

Comment: If I understand you right, you mean, e.g., if cluster A has a capacity of 1x and cluster B has a capacity of 2x, _Xij_ gives _i_ a probability of 33% of mapping the database to cluster A, and 66% to cluster B, and I randomly choose from that distribution. Correct?

Comment: The LP relaxation is $\min\{ \lambda : (\forall i) \sum_{j} X_{ij} \ge 1; (\forall j) \sum_{i} L_{ij} X_{ij} \le \lambda C_{ij}; X \ge 0\}$.  The variables are $\lambda$ and the $X_{ij}$'s, where $X_{ij}$ is the fraction of database $i$ mapped to cluster $j$.  The constants are $L_{ij}$ (the load that database $i$ would put on cluster $j$ if mapped there), and $C_{ij}$ (the load capacity of cluster $j$).  First, use an LP solver to solve this LP relaxation.  Then, randomly round it by choosing, for each database $i$, a cluster $\hat j(i)$ as described in my other comment.

Comment: I suppose a greedy heuristic will give a fast and reasonably good solution most of the time. Do you need an optimal solution?

Comment: I'd just sort the items by size, and add each new item in the bucket where it fits tightest. I.e., look at the algorithms for memory allocation, and check the literature on empirical results for them.